# Powershell - iterating through json file

Tags: json, powershell, active-directory

my json file looks like this:

```
[
    {
        "OU":  "ABC",
        "OUDN":  "OU=x,OU=x,DC=x,DC=x,DC=x"
    },
    {
        "OU":  "XYZ",
        "OUDN":  "OU=x,OU=x,DC=x,DC=x,DC=x"
]
```

"OU" is the name of an AD Organizational Unit

"OUDN" is the associated DistinguishedName of the AD Organizational Unit

**I want to get the description (AD-Attribute) of every Organizational Unit in the json File:**

```
Get-ADOrganizationalUnit -Identity "DistinguishedName of the OU"|FT description
```

How can I do that? How can I iterate through my json file?

My approach:

```
$OU = (Get-Content -path "C:\file.json"|ConvertFrom-JSON).OU
$OUDN = (Get-Content -path "C:\file.json"|ConvertFrom-JSON).OUDN

foreach ($item in $OU) {
Get-ADOrganizationalUnit -Identity ????? }
```

THANK YOU SO MUCH!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're very close, you can iterate over the elements of the Json object with the `foreach` loop as you're already doing it:

```
$json = Get-Content 'C:\file.json' | ConvertFrom-Json

$ous = foreach($item in $json) {
    Get-ADOrganizationalUnit $item.OUDN -Properties Description
}

$ous | Select-Object Name, Description
```

Note that you don't need to `Get-Content` two times for each property, each object of your Json holds the values of the two properties (`OU` and `OUDN`):

```
PS /> $json[0]

OU  OUDN
--  ----
ABC OU=x,OU=x,DC=x,DC=x,DC=x

PS /> $json[0].OUDN

OU=x,OU=x,DC=x,DC=x,DC=x
```